# Actual baseline android size to design

Tags: android, screen-size

Which android density baseline should I pick today?

There are so many xdpi screens over there and no so much mdpi today... or isn't?

I heard that you should use a base size and then resize it with a scale, but which size should I use?

mdpi?
xdpi?

Thanks

Comment: **mdpi** is the "base": `1dp = 1px`.

Comment: I normally start with the highest resolution images (I start from xxhdpi, not xxxhdpi) and scale them down, accordingly. But the "base" is and will always remain **mdpi**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up selecting mdpi as baseline for design.

Answer (score 1):

Now a days most of the devices at least fall under **hdpi** range, mdpi/ldpi are being less popular now. So you can think of using hdpi as base.
Also even when you create a new android project, the preview shown for layout is set default to **nexus one** which is **hdpi**.

Comment: I normally start with the highest resolution images (I start from xxhdpi, not xxxhdpi) and scale them down, accordingly. But the "base" is and will always remain **mdpi**.

Comment: Why always? why not hdpi?